# Use hostname for set_real_ip_from in Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker

How to use hostname and not directly IP for `set_real_ip_from` in Nginx? I have a reverse proxy which can change IP as it is restated (it is a Docker container), but I do not want to trust other IPs from the same range (other Docker containers). I am using [skydock](https://github.com/crosbymichael/skydock) to keep DNS entries resolve to correct IP for a container, so is there a way to use that for `set_real_ip_from` instead of static IP?

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.13.1, [trusted addresses may also be specified using a hostname](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#set_real_ip_from).

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want to rewrite your nginx configuration every time you restart that container. Better to just give it a static IP address.

Comment: Not sure if I can assign a static IP address to the container?

Comment: Of course you can, it's a Docker container. Go read the Docker docs on setting up networking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on the Nginx version. It has been supported in Nginx since `1.13.1`, but anything official prior did not support hostnames in the directive as per [Nginx's documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html), so you had to use either an IP address, Classless Inter-Domain Routing ([CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)), or Unix socket:

> ```js
> Syntax:   set_real_ip_from address | CIDR | unix:;
> Default:  —
> Context:  http, server, location
> ```
>
> Defines trusted addresses that are known to send correct replacement addresses. If the special value unix: is specified, all UNIX-domain sockets will be trusted. **Trusted addresses may also be specified using a hostname (1.13.1).**

Comment: Since 1.13.1, [trusted addresses may also be specified using a hostname](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html#set_real_ip_from).

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Mitar ! Good catch !